# Jekyll collection files not generated from md although collection iterates on parent page?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, templating

I'm not sure what I've done. I've added some new pages from my collections folders.

The folders and files are created in the site folder.

However I can iterate my collections and see the links, however the links provide 404 errors as the files aren't being created.

I've re-saved the files as utf8 but this didn't hel, mentioned in a related question.

I've even removed all the files and put back the original test files which did work previously.

Foolishly I didn't have the project under source control.

Obviously jekyll can see them and read their contents and the loops work...

But the files aren't being generated.

```
<h3>User Guides</h3>
{% for user in site.stt_userguides %}
{::nomarkdown}
    <a href="{{ user.url }}">
        <h3>{{ user.title }}</h3>
    </a>
    <p>{{ user.content | markdownify }}</p>
{:/}
{% endfor %}

<h3>Features</h3>
{% for user in site.stt_features %}
{::nomarkdown}
    <a href="{{ user.url }}">
        <h3>{{ user.title }}</h3>
    </a>
    <p>{{ user.content | markdownify }}</p>
{:/}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm using this command ...

```
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

It confirms the files aren't found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to initial configuration issues implementing collections, I had inadvertently removed the `output: true` setting, also useful to add the permalink property under your collection in config.yml.

As shown in the collections section on this page https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/